# Invalid web-app-versionType after Spring Upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic

To support JUnit 5, I recently upgraded a Spring Boot application to version `2.4.7`.

Local development uses an embedded Tomcat server, while all other environments run on a Weblogic server `12.1.3`.

Everything runs locally, but using the Weblogic Server results in the following exception:

```
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  /weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@700d06bb finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@40ce7cdd annotation: APP@/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.46.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml:18:3:18:3: problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '4.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:249)
```

Other questions on the topic led me to check `web.xml`, but it contains `version="3.0"`.
I don't know how to proceed because I don't understand where this comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have this in your pom.xml to exclude packaging of the tomcat jar files when creating the war file?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependencies must have **provided** scope.